# Spring MVC 3 and handling static content - references inside templates

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, staticresource, thymeleaf

we're using Spring 3.1 for our webapp.

We currently map static resources with

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

and inside our skeleton [template](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) we refer to stylesheets like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">
```

What happens now is that I have no issues on loading css and images inside the main pages of the webapp (so like http://www.mysite.com ) but I get 404s inside inner pages (so like http://www.mysite.com/section1/chapter1 )

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

We're **not** using JSP/JSTL. We're using [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/thvsjsp.html).

Comment: I updated my response with Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Themeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/standardurlsyntax.html), it would be something like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/static/css/main.css}">
```

Or you can also use  the `JSTL` `c:url` tag if you are using `JSP` :

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/static/css/main.css" />">
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Spring URL JSTL tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/static/css/main.css" />">
```

This should resolve the absolute URL based on the current context, and will work on HTML nested within subdirectories.